# Logging Traces, errors and messages to remote server?

Tags: c#, sockets, c#-4.0

I have come to situation in my project where i have to write logs(messages, errors, traces) to the remote server through sockets or some other mean. For some reason i can't write anything in to the local disk.

I have remote machine providing services to my application. I thought of writing to the remote machine. Please provide any other ideas if any.

I heard that i can write all logs into telnet port . Please provide info if someone knows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log4net has a TelnetAppender. If you write your logs with Log4Net, you can configure it to run a telnet server which will allow telnet clients to connect to.

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/